# Reliable way of monitoring file changes in a directory using the .NET framework

Tags: c#, .net, polling, filesystemwatcher

I'm looking for a reliable way of looking for changes in a directory.

I have tried using the FileSystemWatcher, but it's rather inaccurate when many small files are created, changed or deleted. It misses about 1 or 2 % of the files in my tests. That is quite a lot when you are adding or changing thousands of files rapidly.

I have tried polling for changes at different intervals 500 ms, 2000 ms etc. In this case I get too many hits. That might have something to do with the resolution of timestamps on the FileInfo object.

So my question is; is it possible, using the .NET Framework, to get the the changes to a directory reliably?

-- 
Christian

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried  increasing the [InternalBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize.aspx)?
What size have you set it to?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx):

---

> Note that a FileSystemWatcher may miss
>   an event when the buffer size is
>   exceeded. To avoid missing events,
>   follow these guidelines: Increase the
>   buffer size by setting the
>   InternalBufferSize property. Avoid
>   watching files with long file names,
>   because a long file name contributes
>   to filling up the buffer. Consider
>   renaming these files using shorter
>   names.

---

Keep your event handling code as short as possible.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to solve my problems for now. Can't make it miss files with a buffer of 64 KB, must run a few more tests to find the optimal settings.